# accessing text from string

Tags: python, string

```
p=['[Inventor] [Full name] BOLLINGER JOSEPH H [Full name] AHN JANET J [Full name] REILLY PATRICIA A [Full name] MIRIPOL JEFFREY E']
```

Required output:

```
BOLLINGER JOSEPH H,AHN JANET J, REILLY PATRICIA A , MIRIPOL JEFFREY E
```

Comment: Hello there, please put any code you have already tried. Stack Overflow is designed to help people with coding problems, not solve the original question entirely.

Comment: What?? Your question is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the approach using python `regex`:

```
data = "[Inventor] [Full name] BOLLINGER JOSEPH H [Full name] AHN JANET J [Full name] REILLY PATRICIA A [Full name] MIRIPOL JEFFREY E"
import re
# Replace [Inventor] and [Full name] with ,
names = re.sub('\[Full name\]|\[Inventor\]', ',', data)
# Now split on ',' and get the non-empty values added in 'names'
names = [name.strip() for name in names.split(',') if name.strip()]
print (names)
```

Output:

```
['BOLLINGER JOSEPH H', 'AHN JANET J', 'REILLY PATRICIA A', 'MIRIPOL JEFFREY E']
```

Comment: m=p.split(']',-1); 
m[-1]
 any other way than this?

Comment: Pls See the updated code